# When do I call boost::asio::streambuf::consume() and boost::asio::streambuf::commit()?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, iostream

I'm trying to understand the `boost::asio::streambuf::consume()` and `boost::asio::streambuf::commit()` calls. In the docs, we have the examples,

```
boost::asio::streambuf b;
std::ostream os(&b);
os << "Hello, World!\n";

// try sending some data in input sequence
size_t n = sock.send(b.data());

b.consume(n); // sent data is removed from input sequence
```

and

```
boost::asio::streambuf b;

// reserve 512 bytes in output sequence
boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type bufs = b.prepare(512);

size_t n = sock.receive(bufs);

// received data is "committed" from output sequence to input sequence
b.commit(n);

std::istream is(&b);
std::string s;
is >> s;
```

I understand these two calls as much as I understand what the documentation says about them - call `consume()` to remove characters from the input sequence inside the `boost::asio::streambuf`, and call `commit()` to move characters from `boost::asio::streambuf`'s output sequence to its input sequence. Fair enough.

When do I *actually* call these? Looking at the `boost::asio::read_until()` source, we have

```
template <typename SyncReadStream, typename Allocator>
std::size_t read_until(SyncReadStream& s,
    boost::asio::basic_streambuf<Allocator>& b, char delim,
    boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
  std::size_t search_position = 0;
  for (;;)
  {
    // Determine the range of the data to be searched.
    typedef typename boost::asio::basic_streambuf<
      Allocator>::const_buffers_type const_buffers_type;
    typedef boost::asio::buffers_iterator<const_buffers_type> iterator;
    const_buffers_type buffers = b.data();
    iterator begin = iterator::begin(buffers);
    iterator start_pos = begin + search_position;
    iterator end = iterator::end(buffers);

    // Look for a match.
    iterator iter = std::find(start_pos, end, delim);
    if (iter != end)
    {
      // Found a match. We're done.
      ec = boost::system::error_code();
      return iter - begin + 1;
    }
    else
    {
      // No match. Next search can start with the new data.
      search_position = end - begin;
    }

    // Check if buffer is full.
    if (b.size() == b.max_size())
    {
      ec = error::not_found;
      return 0;
    }

    // Need more data.
    std::size_t bytes_to_read = read_size_helper(b, 65536);
    b.commit(s.read_some(b.prepare(bytes_to_read), ec));
    if (ec)
      return 0;
  }
}
```

You can see that, as the documentation says, `boost::asio::read_until()` is implemented in terms of `SyncReadStream`'s `read_some()`.

To me, that says that

1. `SyncReadStream::read_some()` does NOT call `boost::asio::streambuf::commit()`
2. `boost::asio::read_until()` DOES call `boost::asio::streambuf::commit()`
3. Neither of these seem to be documented - neither in `boost::asio::read_until()`'s documentation, nor in `SyncReadStream`'s docs.
4. I don't know whether I'm supposed to be calling `boost::asio::streambuf::commit()` at all?

With my synchronous code I certainly don't seem to need it, not when I'm calling the free functions `boost::asio::read()` and `boost::asio::read_until()`. I have it in my async code in my handlers mostly because the examples I used had it, but I'm not sure about calling it then, either. When I try to use a `boost::asio::streambuf` with `stringstream`'s and `std::string`'s, `commit()` doesn't seem to play a role - nothing gets halted or stuck without calling `commit()` on the `streambuf`.

Can anyone sort this out for me?

Comment: I'd like to see some definitive documentation on this. I can't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

Asio defines a number of [auxiliary free functions (read_xxx)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html) that accept `asio::streambuf`, and they care to `prepare` and `commit` it.

On the other hand, if you'd like to use `asio::streambuf` with [lower-level functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some.html) that accept a model of [`MutableBufferSequence` concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html), you have to call `streambuf::prepare()`, which returns an objects that meets `MutableBufferSequence` concept, pass this object as a buffer, and after the function fills it - call commit().

In both cases, after you've read `n` bytes of data from the `streambuf`, you have to call `consume(n)` - in order to consume the input sequence.

Answer (score 1):

`read_until` uses `read_some` in his implementation. So, `read_some` calls `streambuf::commit` and `read_until` does not (directly).

Usually you don't need to call `commit` and `consume`, but if you want to do something with buffer data - this can be a way to do this. For example, if you using a binary protocol, which cannot be properly checked with `read_until`.